# $.ajax не передает в dataType:json только в dataType:html

Tags: ajax, json

Вопрос собственно в заголовке. Есть код

```
cell = $(this).attr("id");
$.ajax({
  url:"urv/GetTaskAjax",
  method:"POST",
  data:{cell:cell},
  dataType:'html',
  success:function(data){
    console.log(data);
...
```

передача cell на сервер происходит только, если dataType:html.
При dataType:'json'- на сервер ничего не приходит.

Разобраться помог ответ  Максим К.

```
<?php //3.php
if (isset($_POST['cell'])){
    echo json_encode($_POST, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
    exit();
}
?>
<p id="qwerty">Click</p>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" >
    $(document).ready().on('click', 'p', function(event) {
        var cell = $(this).attr("id");
        $.ajax({
            url: "3.php",
            method: "POST",
            data: {cell: cell, task: "Задача №1"},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.cell);
                console.log(data.task);
                console.debug(data);
            },
            error: function (xhr, error){
                console.debug(xhr); console.debug(error);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ну так и смотри настройки сервера.

Comment: А ты уверен, что на сервер не приходит? я на 98% уверен, что серверный обработчик не отдает `json`, поэтому ты не видишь ответ от сервера в обработчике `success`, добавь коллбэк `error` и увидишь, что есть ошибка запроса.

Comment: спасибо, разобрался